# PHP optimizing use of file_put_contents function

Tags: php, performance, io

I'm querying the database and then storing returned data to XML file with file_put_contents(). I'm wondering which way of invoking this function is better. Note that $data is large array and variable $rss can contain a big string in this case.

At first I implemented something like this:

```
foreach($data as $item)
{
    $rss .= '<title>'.getTitle($item['id']).'</title>';
    $rss .= '<data>'.getData($item['id']).'</data>.';
    file_put_contents($this->fileRss, $rss);
    unset($rss);
}
```

And then I changed above to:

```
foreach($data as $item)
{
    $rss .= '<title>'.getTitle($item['id']).'</title>';
    $rss .= '<data>'.getData($item['id']).'</data>.';
}

file_put_contents($this->fileRss, $rss);
```

Which way is better? Making a big, big variable $rss and then saving it or saving quite small variable every time? I'm not sure but I think IO operations are slower than memory operations so first way is better. Only problem may be memory limit.

Comment: have you tried timing it? This might give you some indication.

Comment: How can I do that? I've tested both using... watch. Both executed in the same time i think.

Comment: Do you mean to use `.=` every time? Or do you want to reinitialize `$rss` on each loop iteration?

Comment: In example nr. 1 it's necessary to reinitialize $rss on each iteration or use $rss = 'text'; (without dot) at first line. I don't know if this makes any difference. In example nr 2. I can use .= every time to create big string and then save it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example is incorrect, unless you add  FILE_APPEND to file_put_contents.

```
file_put_contents($this->fileRss, $rss, FILE_APPEND);
```

I would rather manually open the file before the loop, write each chunk of rss data inside the loop, and close the file after the loop.

```
$file = fopen($this->fileRss, 'w');
foreach($data as $item)
{
    $rss = '';
    $rss .= '<title>'.getTitle($item['id']).'</title>';
    $rss .= '<data>'.getData($item['id']).'</data>.';
    fwrite($file, $rss);
}
fclose($file);
```

This way you do not store all the rss entries in memory, and you avoid opening and closing the file in each iteration. 
I have also replaced the `unset` with `$rss = '';` to avoid garbage collection inside the loop.

Comment: file_fut_contents is extremely slow compared to your solution, so it worth to replace it (if there are many function calls).